# What's a good CMS to integrate with an existing Java website (needs good API's)

Tags: java, content-management-system

We have a large existing website (written in Java/Spring/Hibernate/JSP) and want to add a Content Management System to allow our employees to manage sections of existing pages and in certain cases the body of entire pages (such as jobs/contact/press-release/etc).

The catch is most open-source CMS's we've looked at like Drupal, Radiant, Joomla, etc seem to be designed so that you build an entire website on-top of the CMS. Whereas we want a CMS that's designed to be integrated in an existing site (perhaps via API's).

Any suggestions?

Comment: After a lot of digging and research I found Hippo CMS http://www.onehippo.org/ which is Java based and can be integrated with existing Java web application using their HST-2 (Hippo Site Toolkit). Finally an enterprise quality CMS where integration with large existing websites isn't an afterthought!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We went through a vetting process and chose [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/).

This might help you pick one that is right for you.
[Open Source Content Management Systems (CMS) in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/content-managment-systems)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Did you end up configuring Alfresco to sit off to the side and then you pull in the contents into your existing site with API calls? Or did you somehow manage to get Alfresco to integrate with your existing webapp so that it can actually serve pages?

Comment: I wasn't involved in the project, so I'm not sure what the implementation details are.  I'm pretty sure it's sitting off to the side and our controllers are doing API calls to it to build the models before sending it off to the view - so Alfresco is not managing our pages, just assets we have on the page.  That's all just a guess though.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Alfresco. Uses Spring for IOC and other standard Java technologies. It is pretty well documented, and easy to follow. In fact, the few times I couldn't get what I needed from the documentation, I was able to dig into the source code and figure it out pretty quickly. Very easy to write extensions and mods for it.

Comment: How did you go about integrating Alfresco with your existing website? Do you get the content out of it with API calls or do you actually have Alfresco responsible for serving certain pages?

Comment: Its deployed in a J2EE container. It can be installed standalone, it comes with a Tomcat with the default installation. We deployed it in JBoss. With an existing website, its probably best to deploy to a seperate webapp and make calls to Alfresco for documents. We didn't actually publish webpages with Alfresco, but used it for managing XML documents authored in Word. I wrote a piece that took that document and published it to various formats via the DITA Open Toolkit...

Comment: @BryceFischer This doesn't answer the question. It should either be a comment or should be deleted or modified.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at [LifeRay](http://www.liferay.com/) as it is an enterprise portal and supports cms integration.

Comment: This is exactly what he said he does not want

Answer (score 0):

Hi friends, I suggest `Liferay 6.1`, because I work with it some times, it's better to customize the portal than others, as far I know.

Hope I gave some info what I know regard it, it may help some one.

Comment: Liferay is my own experiance.

Answer (score 0):

We have a Wicket application and also had the challenge to hook this up with a CMS. As most CMS players want to control the delivery tier, we where also looking for a CMS with a strong sepereation of concern and a way to just retrieve the content through an API. We have chosen Hippo CMS for their [RESTful API Support](http://www.onehippo.org/7_8/library/concepts/rest/restful-api-support---plain-jax-rs-services.html) to solve our problem.