# Looking for an CMS that can be plugged into a Spring MVC Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, content-management-system

I am looking for a simple CMS that can be pluged in into a Spring MVC Application, in contrast to a CMS where I can plugin a Spring Application.

Let me first explain what I NOT want: I do not want a CMS like Magnolia/Blossom where I can add some Spring Plugins into the CMS.

What I NEED, is the other way around; I need some CMS that is controlled by MY application.  (The CMS is only a very small part of it, not the main part.)

Assume this two use cases:

- (**Static Pages**) I have Spring Web Application, and now need some function where a (Admin)-User can update the “terms and condition” page, modify some content (Text and Image)on the start page... – so almost editing “static” pages.
- (**Content for Domainobjects**) My Application has some domain objects, and a User needs to add some large description (Text and Images) for this domain objects.  An Example would be: Some kind of a shop system where the shop owner wants to have fancy and individual Description pages for every product.

Does anybody know such a CMS?

Comment: Although not an answer, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841546/whats-a-good-cms-to-integrate-with-an-existing-java-website-needs-good-apis

Answer (score 1):

[Walrus CMS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/walruscms/) is very simple and is based on Spring, Tiles, Hibernate, and Freemarker.  It allows an admin user to [edit](http://www.cmscritic.com/cms-admin-dashboard-not/) the website directly in-place.  It's lean on features, but seems exactly what you are seeking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any direct experience with it (yet), but [this SO dicussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410445/what-is-a-good-java-based-content-management-system-for-us-and-why#answer-4463250) from a couple of years ago recommends [Riot CMS](http://www.riotfamily.org/index.html), which is built on Spring, and appears to be designed to be embedded, rather than used as a stand-alone application.

I spent a couple of minutes with the demo, and it looks pretty good. I'll definitely be checking it out in more detail.