# Integrating CMS with Spring MVC Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, liferay, opencms

I have a Spring MVC based application and there is a need to implement Blog with tags in it. I searched for various ways to integrate CMS with Spring MVC application, I come up with Open CMS, Mangolina CMS. But the way how they integrate with Spring MVC wont suit my requirements.

I am looking out for a solution where in I can implement CMS(Blog) without making any changes/minimal changes to existing application. The current application use JSP as views. 
I found similar question here
[Looking for an CMS that can be plugged into a Spring MVC Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629222/looking-for-an-cms-that-can-be-plugged-into-a-spring-mvc-application), but the answers given does not suit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After various Java based solutions and understanding their complexity in integrating with my application, I considered installing WordPress on Tomcat to be the best solution. In my case, I can hardly spare a couple of days for blog as it is just an additional functionality to my app.

I followed below url http://www.studytrails.com/blog/installing-wordpress-on-j2ee-app-serveer-apache-tomcat-using-quercus/ in installing WordPress on Tomcat and pointed myapplication.com/blog to wordpress application. Hope it may help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with few java CMS like Liferay, it is always a pain. For example Liferay CMS works based on JSR-286 which will force you to create Portlets. There are ways to extended every layer in Liferay but that require a fair level of expertise to make it work, especially when your application grows bigger it becomes a bottleneck.

Can you provide fundamental reason why you want to bundle both? Why can't you keep it as two separate applications, deploy and maintain it as two separate applications. May be an httpd can be used to redirect the traffic based on URL pattern.

That being said if you want to integrate your old web application to Liferay, follow this [link](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+Web+Application+Integrator).